# Why prep 'on' used in the phrase "being held on an additional $50,000 bond"?

Tags: prepositions

> Stine was arrested and booked with four misdemeanors including resisting arrest, criminal trespass and disorderly conduct. He was also charged with felony robbery for the incident and is being held **on** an additional $50,000 bond.

As I understand "*being held on an additional $50,000 bond*", it means Stine was taken into custody and he would be bailed out after he pays that additional $50,000 bond. Is my understanding to that phrase correct? why is 'on' used? Maybe, it's just an idiomatic usage in that setting and there is no reason for it. I figure "*being held **over** an additional $50,000 bond*" probably denotes the same meaning here. I am unsure if "held on" is a set phrase here.

The [full source](http://www.foxnews.com/food-drink/2018/08/12/man-accused-filling-water-cup-with-soda-at-fast-food-restaurant-tased-charged-with-robbery.html).

Comment: "hold on a bond" is read more smoothly.

Comment: @马化腾 but it's actually "being held on a bond".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: it is indeed a purely idiomatic expression, and there is no reason for it beyond that. When someone is being held in jail, that person is being *held on* a certain bond, and also *held on* certain criminal charges.

*Held over* is used in relation to a trial or arraignment: someone is *held over for trial* or *held over for arraignment*.